# How to produce a scatter plot of dates vs magnitudes in R?

Tags: r, date

This is what i have done so far but its wrong.

```
    earthquakes<- c(6.6,6.8,8.4)
    dates <- (13/02/2001 ,28/02/2001,23/06/2001)
    plot(earthquakes,dates)
```

I have only started learning R. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
earthquakes<- c(6.6,6.8,8.4)
dates <- as.Date(c("13/02/2001", "28/02/2001", "23/06/2001"), format="%d/%m/%Y")
plot(dates, earthquakes)
```

You had a few issues:

- Dates should be in quotes (otherwise R will think you're trying to do arithmetic (i.e. 13 divided by 02 divied by 2001)
- To convert dates to actual date objects, use `as.Date`, pass a vector of dates (this is the `c(...` part), and then specify the format that they are in so that R knows what to do with the strings
- you had x and y swapped

Note, the `as.Date` step is not strictly necessary, but if you don't do that, then the `x` axis of the plot will plot every item equidistant, irrespective of how far apart the dates actually are in time.

Comment: thank you BrodieG!!! you are a life saver. By the way, if i have say 150 observations, is it wise to do it the same way or is there a better method?

Comment: @ben, 150 obs is perfectly fine.  Also, if this answers your question, please consider marking it as answered.